# Jenkins - Multiple instances

Tags: jenkins

We have around `30 Jenkins installs` across our organization, both `Windows` and `Linux`. They are all used for different tasks and by different teams (e.g. *managing Azure*, *manipulating data*, *testing applications* etc.)

I have been tasked with looking at whether we could bring these all into one 'Jenkins Farm' but as far as I can see such a thing doesn't exist? Ultimately 'we' want some control and to minimize the footprint of Jenkins. The articles I have found don't recommend using a single Master server (with multiple `nodes`) because of the following:

- No role-based access for projects (affecting other teams code)
- Plugins can affect all projects
- Single point of failure as there is only one master server

Is it best to leave these on separate servers? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Role based access for projects is possible using 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

However, a single master isn't ideal as you pointed out due to 'Plugins can affect all projects'. Probably best to have separate jenkins master nodes but configure agents such that they can be shared across teams/projects.